# ¿como comparar los datos de una columna en formato json de una tabla con los datos de otra tabla en una BD con eloquent - laravel8?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join

estoy usando dos tablas de mi BD una llamada `products` y otra llamada `notifications` en la tabla notifications hay un campo llamado **data**, donde se guardan ciertos campos de la tabla **products** en formato json, este es un ejemplo de un registro del campo **data**: `{"id":5,"code":"12312","name":"asda","due_date":"2021-10-29","days":"30","description":"wdwad"}`

Estoy usando eloquent para consultar todos los datos de la tabla `products`, quiero hacer 2 consultas, la primera sería consultar todos los productos que no se encuentren registrados en el campo **data** de la tabla `notifications` y la segunda sería que si están registrados traer los productos que en el campo **days** sean diferentes de 30.

Sé que se usaría el join para unir las 2 tablas, para consultar los datos json de un campo encontré que se usa el json_extract, pero no sé como comparar los datos que están en formato json del campo **data** en la tabla `notifications` con los campos de la tabla `products` usando un join.

Imporvisé algo como esto para la primera consulta pero no funcionó:

```
Product::selectRaw('products.*,notifications.json_extract(data, $.id) AS jsonidproduct')
         ->orderby(products.id)
         ->join('notifications','products.id','!=','jsonidproduct')
         ->get()
```

para la segunda consulta no tengo las bases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

1.- Con emplear el [operador `->`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses) puedes acceder a la clave que indiques  de la siguiente forma:

```
....................'data->id')
```

- Esto claro si es que id es la clave que usas para vincular

2.- Posterior creo que si lo que buscas es obtener aquellos productos que no están relacionados con algún registro en el json de data entonces puedes:

- Realiza un left join (**esto originalmente te mostrará tanto los productos con algún registro relacionado en data como aquellos que no**)
- Finalmente para dejar en la salida solo aquellos productos cuyo id no esté en `data` puedes evaluar con `whereNull` el identificador de los ya mencionados.

Quedando la query de este modo:

```
Product::select('products.*', 'notifications.data->id AS jsonidproduct')
     ->leftJoin('notifications','products.id','=','notifications.data->id')
     ->whereNull('notifications.data->id')
     ->orderBy('products.id')
     ->get();
```

Tu consulta inicial tiene otros detalles menores como:

- Falta de comillas en el argumento del método `orderBy`
- Respecto del punto anterior, procuremos [seguir el nombre de los métodos tal cual son](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#orderby)
- No debería ser: `notifications.json_extract` desde el momento que `notifications` es el nombre de la tabla y dicha función no es una columna (*aquí recomiendo repases la sintaxis empleada*)
- El punto y coma del final de la sentencia

Comment: Mi mejor recomendación es publicar una nueva pregunta, en comentarios la ayuda se puede extender demasiado, recomiendo eliminarlo y proceder con la publicación **aportando todos los detalles necesarios**